# Report order by date column descending in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my query:

```
SELECT
  DR.name as tradername,
  convert(varchar,DR.Receiveddate,103) as recdate,
  DR.Recamount,
  DR.Chequeno,
  DR.Remark,
  DR.Updatedby 
FROM K_HM_ChicksaleDueReport DR 
where 
  DR.Receiveddate between @fromdate and @todate 
  and DR.name=@name

union all

Select 
  CS.name as tradername,
  convert(varchar,CS.chicksplaceddate,103) as recdate,
  CS.Recamount,
  '' as chequeno,
  'Direct' as Remark,
  CS.Updatedby 
from K_HM_ChickSales CS
where 
  CS.Recamount>0 
  and  CS.chicksplaceddate between @fromdate and @todate 
  and CS.name=@name 

order by recdate desc
```

Using this I am getting report by only day wise descending order. But what I want is total **dd/mm/yyyy** wise descending order.

Something like:

```
22/05/2014
21/05/2014
10/04/2014
 5/03/2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select tradername,convert(varchar,recdate,103)as recdate,Recamount,chequeno,
remark,updatedby from (
SELECT  name as tradername,Receiveddate as recdate,Recamount,Chequeno,
Remark,Updatedby FROM K_HM_ChicksaleDueReport  
where Receiveddate between @fromdate and @todate 
and name like '%'+@name+'%'
union all
Select name as tradername,chicksplaceddate as recdate,Recamount,''as chequeno,'Direct' as Remark,Updatedby from K_HM_ChickSales 
where Recamount>0 and  chicksplaceddate between @fromdate and @todate and name like '%'+@name+'%')a   order by a.recdate  desc

end

else
select tradername,convert(varchar,recdate,103)as recdate,Recamount,chequeno,remark,updatedby from(
SELECT name as tradername,Receiveddate as recdate,Recamount, Chequeno,
Remark,Updatedby 
FROM K_HM_ChicksaleDueReport  where Receiveddate between @fromdate 
and @todate and name=@name
union all
Select name as tradername,chicksplaceddate as recdate,Recamount,''as chequeno,
'Direct' as Remark,Updatedby from K_HM_ChickSales 
where Recamount>0 and  chicksplaceddate between @fromdate and @todate 
and name=@name)a order by a.recdate  desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `recdate` is a VARCHAR it orders by individual characters.

Try casting / converting `recdate` back to `DATE` first, so like this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(recdate AS DATETIME) DESC
```

Comment: it is giving error like this...Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure k_GetChickTraderReport, Line 42
Invalid column name 'recdate'.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Procedure k_GetChickTraderReport, Line 42
Type date is not a defined system type.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure k_GetChickTraderReport, Line 42
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: I guess you're using pre SQL2008? Try DATETIME then. You were already using `recdate` to order by, right? So the first error message is not new?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your query like that i guess

```
select tradername,
 convert(varchar,recdate,103) as recdate,Recamount,Chequeno,Remark,Updatedby from (
SELECT
  DR.name as tradername,
  DR.Receiveddate as recdate,
  DR.Recamount,
  DR.Chequeno,
  DR.Remark,
  DR.Updatedby 
FROM K_HM_ChicksaleDueReport DR 
where 
  DR.Receiveddate between @fromdate and @todate 
  and DR.name=@name

union all

Select 
  CS.name as tradername,
  CS.chicksplaceddate as recdate,
  CS.Recamount,
  '' as chequeno,
  'Direct' as Remark,
  CS.Updatedby 
from K_HM_ChickSales CS
where 
  CS.Recamount>0 
  and  CS.chicksplaceddate between @fromdate and @todate 
  and CS.name=@name 

) as o
order by recdate desc
```